# Reset control's parent in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

If I add a control to a canvas and than removes it, I can not re-add it to the same canvas (or to any other canvas for that matter) any idea how can I reset the parent?

mainCanvas.Children.Add(item);
mainCanvas.Children.Remove(item);

mainCanvas.Children.Add(item); // Will throw an exception that parent was already set.

Thanks, 
Eden.

Comment: Can you show a code that it is not work I will try to help you

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there is not something else going on in your code?

I just tried a new wpf application with :

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Button b = new Button();
        b.Content = "hello";
        Canvas c = new Canvas();
        c.Children.Add(b);
        c.Children.Remove(b);
        c.Children.Add(b);
        Content = c;
    }
```

and it worked fine. Have you got any collection changed delegates?

Comment: Thanks. I inherited a code base which is a mess... I'll have to dig in.